# JavaMailSender timeout doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, timeout, smtpclient

i am using javaMail 1.4.4 and Spring 3.2.
I want set timeout on my javamail connection when i send a email, but doesn't work. 
The connection doesn't expire after the period established.
This is my config

```
public JavaMailSenderImpl createJavaMailSender(String smtpName) {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mail = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mail.setHost(smtpName);
    Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", "20000");
    mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "20000");
    mail.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
    return mail;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? what's it doing? (p.s. that applies to *every question you ever ask here* - tell us what's going on *as precisely as possible*).

Comment: i change the post. Thanks

Comment: Use smtps.. like mail.transport.protocol=smtps, mail.smtps.timeout=2000 etc.